# Multiple animations in python with matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, animation

I would like to use matplotlib's animation capabilities to display *and* save *multiple* animations. Previously, I was just using pyplot with a short pause at each step to *fake* the animation, but I did not find a way to save these "animations" as videos, so I'm switching to using the real animations. Here is a dummy version of my code (which will run) when I started:

```py
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

class Hallway:
    def __init__(self):
        self.end_pos = 5
        self.cur_pos = 0

    def setup(self):
        self.cur_pos = 0

    def go(self, decision):
        if decision == 0 and self.cur_pos > 0:
            self.cur_pos -= 1
        elif decision == 1:
            self.cur_pos += 1
        done = self.cur_pos >= self.end_pos
        return done
    
    def draw(self, fig):
        fig.clear()
        ax = fig.gca()
        ax.set(xlim=(-0.5, 5.5), ylim=(-0.5, 0.5))
        ax.scatter(self.cur_pos, 0., s=350)
        plt.draw()
        plt.pause(0.01)

sim = Hallway()
for num_sim in range(5):
    print("running simulation {}".format(num_sim))
    sim.setup()
    sim.draw(plt.gcf())
    while True:
        done = sim.go(np.random.randint(0,2))
        sim.draw(plt.gcf())
        if done:
            break
    # Save animation here
```

Key things to note in here:

1. The next state of the Hallway generated with `go`
2. The frames are generated with `draw`
3. The done condition indicates when the simulation should end
4. Once an animation ends, I want to save it, but we're not done! After saving the animation, I want to launch a *new* one. This will happen 5 times with the outer loop.

So I changed my code around so that I could use an animation object, and this is what it is now:

```py
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.animation import FuncAnimation
import numpy as np

class Hallway:
    def __init__(self):
        self.end_pos = 5
        self.cur_pos = 0

    def setup(self):
        self.cur_pos = 0

    def go(self, decision):
        if decision == 0 and self.cur_pos > 0:
            self.cur_pos -= 1
        elif decision == 1:
            self.cur_pos += 1
        done = self.cur_pos >= self.end_pos
        return done
    
    def draw(self, fig):
        fig.clear()
        ax = fig.gca()
        ax.set(xlim=(-0.5, 5.5), ylim=(-0.5, 0.5))
        ax.scatter(self.cur_pos, 0., s=350)
        plt.draw()
        plt.pause(0.01)

sim = Hallway()
for num_sim in range(5):
    print("running simulation {}".format(num_sim))
    sim.setup()
    all_done = False
    fig = plt.figure()

    def gen_frame_until_done(): # Using a generator to give me frames as long as not all_done
        global all_done
        i = 0
        while not all_done:
            i += 1
            yield i
    
    def animate(i): # Animate function takes the place of the while loop
        sim.draw(fig)
        done = sim.go(np.random.randint(0,2))
        if done:
            global all_done
            all_done = True
            sim.draw(fig)
    
    anim = FuncAnimation(fig, animate, frames=gen_frame_until_done, repeat=False)
    plt.show()
    # anim.save(...)
```

This will run, but it won't quite give me what I want. It will show *only one* animation and the terminal will show `running simulation 0`. When `all_done` is triggered and the simulation is over, the program will wait for me to exit the plot window. Once I exit, the program will continue to the next simulation and repeat.

I don't like that I have to manually exit the window. I got a little hack semi-working by replacing the blocking `plt.show()` with

```py
plt.show(block=False)
plt.pause(3)
plt.close()
```

This will allow the program to continue without having to manually exit the window. However, it will only allow 3 seconds of the animation to display before going on to the next one.

What I want:

- I want to be able to display the simulation until it is over. When it is over, I want the window to automatically close.
- I want the next simulation to run with a new animation window right after the previous one.

Again, I'm using the animation objects because I need to be able to save the animations as videos. But if there's another way to do this, I'm definitely open to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you add a `plt.close()` call inside the `if done` clause of the `animate` function, the plot window will close when the simulation finishes, and the next window will open with the next simulation.

So that the next animation doesn't require any interaction with the mouse, we also need to add `block=False` to the `plt.show`; we can the check whether `all_done` is true or false, and `plt.pause()` if the animation is not done.

For example:

```
for num_sim in range(5):
    print("running simulation {}".format(num_sim))
    sim.setup()
    all_done = False
    fig = plt.figure()

    def gen_frame_until_done(): # Using a generator to give me frames as long as not all_done
        global all_done
        i = 0
        while not all_done:
            i += 1
            yield i
    
    def animate(i): # Animate function takes the place of the while loop
        sim.draw(fig)
        done = sim.go(np.random.randint(0,2))
        if done:
            global all_done
            all_done = True
            sim.draw(fig)
            plt.close(fig)
    
    anim = FuncAnimation(fig, animate, frames=gen_frame_until_done, repeat=False)
    
    plt.show(block=False)
    while all_done is False:
        plt.pause(1)
```

Comment: thanks for the response! This is a big help forward. This doesn't fully work for me though because the animation will play a single simulation, then the window will close. Then it will freeze. It will not go on to the next animation UNLESS I interact with the computer somehow, be either clicking the mouse or moving it around. If I just sit and watch, it will play an animation, close the window, and then it seems to wait for me to do something... Running on Mac 10.14.6

Comment: @KindaTechy you are right. I think my edit fixes that, by setting `block=False` in the `plt.show()` at the end, and then checking against `all_done` to decide whether it needs to pause or not

Comment: Awesome @tmdavison! This has solved my issue. I wish I understood better how plt works so that I could better understand how this code runs... I'll just note here that I have to put the anim.save(...) function above plt.show(block=False), otherwise I cannot save and render.